# How to hide an ACTIVITY to call another ACTIVITY and run it on background and show it again?

Tags: java, android

****I'm working on an android project, where I have to give a facility of reading eBook while listening audio songs on Samsung tab(Android 3.2 and above). For that I need to hide the audio player view to go to the file browser to select eBook.

I need your help to find out, how to hide the **AudioPlayer** activity and again show the same(player view) from any place.

In short I want to make make AudioPlayer view similar to minimize option in Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is run the audio player as a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService) and build an activity as an interface to it. Then even if the audio player activity is closed the music will continue playing.